# groovy 3.0.x asString() method doesn't replace { }

Tags: xml, groovy

After upgrading jdk from 11 to 17, I have to upgrade groovy from 2.5.14 to groovy 3.0.8 +.
After I ran my class which serialize a doc, this is the serialization part :

```
`XmlUtil.serialize(node)`
```

And at that line I'm getting below error :

```
`[Fatal Error] :1:11: Element type "Element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
ERROR:  'Element type "Element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".'

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 11; Element type "Element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".

groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 11; Element type "Element" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(XmlUtil.java:475)
    at groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(XmlUtil.java:461)
    at groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(XmlUtil.java:191)
    at groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(XmlUtil.java:100)
    at groovy.xml.XmlUtil$serialize.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at com.myproject.XML.getSerialized(XML.groovy:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at     java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:107)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodMetaProperty$GetBeanMethodMetaProperty.getProperty(MethodMetaProperty.java:76)
    at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.getProperty(GetEffectivePogoPropertySite.java:85)
    at  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:341)
    at com.myproject.XMLTest.getSerialized(XMLTest.groovy:30
```

I debugged, and found that `asString()` method which is called right in `serialize()` method in XmlUtils gives different output in these groovy versions:

groovy 2.5.14 :

`<Element xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> ...`

groovy 3.0.8

`<Element {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation="...xsd">`

this is at the beginning of xml content, what follows is not changed

I've tried and groovy version 3.0.16, but got the same exception.

Does anyone have any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: there is probably an error in your code. Please provide a code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: the code was not changed at all, only the following versions of the dependencies were changed : 
groovy-all:2.5.7 - groovy-all:3.0.16 ; 
spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5 - spock-core:2.4-M1-groovy-3.0 ; 
junit:4.12 - junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0 ; 
and jdk 11- jdk 17.

would it still be necessary to show the code?

Comment: Yes, please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
- looks like you have updated the packages for `XmlUtil`, so there are
  at least more changes to the code than just updating the packages.
  Since the problem is around the namespace, you should isolate the
  code, that generates that `Element` and ideally make it run with
  `groovy(sh)`.